# How do I modify this command to play an audio file every 10 minutes?

Tags: cron

How do I modify this command to play an audio file every 10 minutes?

```
*/15 * * * *   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 /usr/bin/play -n synth 10 sin 20
```

Comment: Hi. hhhm... switch 15 by 10. or "0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * "

Comment: That's a super low frequency. Be careful not to blow your speakers. Something like `sin 100` might be more reasonable for most people.

Comment: If you want a tone that is inaudible that won't damage your speakers, I suggest using `sin 1` instead of `sin 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to set (edit) a cron job for your current user:

```
crontab -e
```

Then, paste the following line at the end of the file:

```
*/10 * * * *   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 /usr/bin/play -n synth 10 sin 100
```

After you are done editing the file:

**If your system uses nano editor**, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.

**If your system uses vim editor**, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> then type `:wq` and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

---

This will play the tone once every 10 minutes starting at each hour (at 10, 20, 30, . . . , 60).

I changed `sin 20` to `sin 100` because `sin 20` is a low frequency that may damage speakers if played too loudly on some systems. However, you can change this back to `sin 20` if you would like. *If you want a tone that is inaudible that won't damage your speakers, I suggest using* `sin 1` *instead.*

The sine tone will play for 10 seconds as specified by the command option `synth 10` and you can change that also (like `synth 1` to set for 1 second for example).